# Specifying "Include" download parameter in Tableau API with Python

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am trying to automate sending Tableau dashboards in PDF format for my company in Slack. I have built code which signs in Tableau Server, takes necessary view in workbook and sends it to Slack channel. The problem is that some of dashboards are long and while downloading it is necessary to specify "Include" parameter with value "Specific sheets from this dashboard" and select all. As it is impossible to do with TSC library I am looking for another solution for this problem. Please help.

[image: Here is the parameter i am writing about]

Here is code:

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC
import PyPDF2
import requests
import json
import os
import datetime
def delete_system_files(folder_path):
    import os

    try:
        # List all files in the folder
        files = os.listdir(folder_path)

        for file in files:
            # Construct the full file path
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)

            # Check if it's a file (not a subdirectory)
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                # Delete the file
                os.remove(file_path)
                print(f"Deleted: {file_path}")

        print("Deletion completed.")
    except OSError as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
delete_system_files(folder_path='/Users')
# Tableau download code
# (Place your Tableau download code here)
# source information
SOURCE_SERVER_NAME = ""
SOURCE_SERVER_USERNAME = ""
SOURCE_SERVER_PASSWORD = ""
SOURCE_SITE_NAME = ''
SOURCE_WORKBOOK_NAME = "Limits_check_up"  # Update to the correct workbook name
PREVIEW_FOLDER_LOCATION = os.getcwd() + "/Documents/Tableau_Zipper/"
PREVIEW_FILE_EXTENSION = ".pdf"

source_server = TSC.Server(SOURCE_SERVER_NAME, use_server_version=True)
source_tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth(SOURCE_SERVER_USERNAME, SOURCE_SERVER_PASSWORD, site_id=SOURCE_SITE_NAME)

with source_server.auth.sign_in(source_tableau_auth):
    print('Logged in to source server successfully')

    req_option = TSC.RequestOptions()
    req_option.filter.add(TSC.Filter(TSC.RequestOptions.Field.Name,
                                     TSC.RequestOptions.Operator.Equals, SOURCE_WORKBOOK_NAME))

    all_workbooks, pagination_item = source_server.workbooks.get(req_option)

    if len(all_workbooks) == 0:
        print('No workbook named {} found.'.format(SOURCE_WORKBOOK_NAME))
    else:
        for workbook in all_workbooks:
            print("Found workbook:", workbook.name)
            try:
                source_server.workbooks.populate_views(workbook)
                for view in workbook.views:
                    pdf_req_option = TSC.PDFRequestOptions(page_type=TSC.PDFRequestOptions.PageType.Unspecified,
                                                           orientation= TSC.PDFRequestOptions.Orientation.Portrait
                                                           
                                                           )
                    source_server.views.populate_pdf(view, pdf_req_option)
                    with open(PREVIEW_FOLDER_LOCATION + view.name + PREVIEW_FILE_EXTENSION, 'wb') as f:
                        f.write(view.pdf)
                    print("File downloaded to:", PREVIEW_FOLDER_LOCATION + view.name + PREVIEW_FILE_EXTENSION)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error:", e)

    # Sign out
    source_server.auth.sign_out()
# Slack message sending function
def send_slack_message(channel, message, file_path, slack_token):
    upload_url = "https://slack.com/api/files.upload"
    post_message_url = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage"

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {slack_token}",
    }
    files = {
        "file": open(file_path, "rb")
    }

    # Upload the file to the Slack channel
    upload_data = {
        "channels": channel,
    }
    upload_response = requests.post(upload_url, headers=headers, files=files, data=upload_data)

    # Check if file upload was successful
    if upload_response.status_code == 200 and upload_response.json().get("ok"):
        file_id = upload_response.json().get("file").get("id")

        # Send a message with the uploaded file
        message_data = {
            "channel": channel,
            "text": message,
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "fallback": "Uploaded File",
                    "color": "#36a64f",
                    "title": "Uploaded File",
                    "title_link": f"https://slack.com/files/{upload_response.json().get('file').get('user')}-{upload_response.json().get('file').get('id')}",
                }
            ],
            "file": file_id
        }
        message_response = requests.post(post_message_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(message_data))

        if message_response.status_code == 200 and message_response.json().get("ok"):
            print("Message sent successfully!")
        else:
            print("Failed to send message. Error:", message_response.text)
    else:
        print("Failed to upload file. Error:", upload_response.text)

# Other necessary code here (e.g., configurations, paths, etc.)

# Execute Tableau download code here

# Merging PDFs (if applicable)
# Merging PDF files from Tableau download
pdf_file_paths = ['/Users/Limits control.pdf']


current_date = datetime.date.today()
current_day = current_date.day
previous_day = current_day - 1
current_month = current_date.strftime("%m")
current_year = current_date.year % 100

# Creating a merged PDF file
output_file_path = f'/Users/Limits_control {current_date.day - 1}.{current_date.strftime("%m")}.{current_date.year % 100}.pdf'
#if not os.path.exists('/Users/d.grisulonoks/Documents/Tableau zipper/'):
 #   os.makedirs('/Users/d.grisulonoks/Documents/Tableau zipper/')

with open(output_file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
    for pdf_path in pdf_file_paths:
        try:
            with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as pdf_file:
                chunk_size = 8192
                while chunk := pdf_file.read(chunk_size):
                    output_file.write(chunk)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error reading file {pdf_path}: {e}")



channel_id = "test-tableau-bot"

# channel_id = "demo"
message_text = f'{previous_day}.{current_month}.{current_year} report hello'
slack_api_token = "" # upload file to Tableau brainstorm
send_slack_message(channel_id, message_text, output_file_path, slack_api_token)
```

It downloads only half of the views